# PHP web-textbox syntax highlighting

Tags: php, ide, textbox

I'm looking for a solution where users can copy/paste PHP code into a textbox and it will be highlighted like it is inside an IDE. (Like stackoverflow does when you paste a code snippet) Any links/ideas/more information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/). It does almost everything for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's [highlight_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php)

Very simple example...

```
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="str"></textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
highlight_string($_POST['str']);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://phpanywhere.net/

Answer (score 0):

Two sites that I use are [gist.github.com](http://gist.github.com) and [codepad.org](http://codepad.org).  You might want to check out what libraries they're using, or just take advantage of their sites and avoid the work yourself by linking through to 'em.